Unterschied zwischen "ähnlich", "wie" und "ähnlich wie"?
Ich möchte die Unterschiede zwischen den Ausdrücken "ähnlich", "wie" und "ähnlich wie" besser verstehen. Dabei interessieren mich sowohl die allgemeinen Bedeutungen als auch der praktische Gebrauch im Alltag.
Hier ist mein aktuelles Verständnis:
"Ähnlich": Bedeutet „teilweise analog, in manchem übereinstimmend“. Das ist klar.
"Wie": Drückt Gleichheit aus, aber was genau bedeutet „Gleichheit“ in diesem Zusammenhang? Ist damit absolute Übereinstimmung gemeint, wie in der Mathematik(5=5), oder kann „wie“ auch eine teilweise Ähnlichkeit ausdrücken?
"Ähnlich wie": Wie unterscheidet sich das von den beiden anderen Ausdrücken?
Zusätzlich interessieren mich die folgenden Beispiele:
Er ist seinem Vater ähnlich.
Er ist (ganz) wie sein Vater.
Er ist ähnlich wie sein Vater.
Meine Hauptfrage ist: Welche Unterschiede gibt es hier in der Bedeutung oder im Gebrauch? Beziehen sie sich auf Intensität, Art der Beziehung oder etwas anderes?


aber was genau bedeutet „Gleichheit“ in diesem Zusammenhang?

Sprache besteht nicht nur aus Lautäußerungen ("Wortschatz") und den Regeln, wie man diese abändert ("Grammatik"), sondern zu einem erheblichen Teil aus Kontext. Sprachverständnis ist nicht die Dechiffrierung von Inhalten, sondern (auch) deren Interpretation.

Er ist seinem Vater ähnlich.

Das ist eine generalisierte Aussage, die ohne Kontext etwa so viel bedeutet wie:

In den meisten Punkten, an die ich jetzt grade denke, ist die Übereinstimmung zwischen ihm und seinem Vater ziemlich groß.

Es könnte trotzdem sein, daß seinem Vater das Erlernen assyrischer Keilschrift viel schwerer gefallen ist, als ihm (ich wette: and den Unterschied haben Sie vorher nicht gedacht), aber beide sind groß, leicht übergewichtig, glatzköpfig, trinken gerne Tee und sind Altphilologen von Beruf.
Jetzt erweitern wir das Beispiel. Gesagt wurde vorher tatsächlich das:

Sein Vater konnte niemals an einer Hieroglypheninschrift vorbeigehen, ohne sich sofort an die Entzifferung zu machen. Er ist wie sein Vater.

Preisfrage: in welchen Eigenschaften stimmen die beiden überein, damit der Satz richtig ist? Und, Zusatzfrage: ist es für die Richtigkeit des Satzes von Belang, ob beide ein Loch im hinteren Backenzahn links oben haben oder nur einer von von ihnen?
Das ist Kontext! Die Frage "was genau bedeutet 'Gleichheit'" ist ohne Verweis auf diesen Kontext nicht zu beantworten, beziehungsweise nur mit einem nichtssagenden "kommt drauf an".
Kommen wir zur Hauptfrage:

Welche Unterschiede gibt es hier in der Bedeutung oder im Gebrauch?

Antwort: deutliche!

Er ist seinem Vater ähnlich.

bedeutet, daß es - in einem nicht genannten Kontext - eine weitgehende Übereinstimmung zwischen den Personen "er" und "sein Vater" gibt, die allerdings nur weitgehend, nicht vollkommen ist. Ansonsten müßte es lauten:

Er ist seinem Vater gleich.

oder:

Er ist (ganz) wie sein Vater.

wobei letzteres tendenziell eher auf immaterielle Qualitäten abstellt. Ohne weiteren Kontext bedeutet das eher, daß sie beide cholerisch, kinderlieb, wahrheitsliebend oder spielsüchtig sind, als daß beide dieselbe Haarfarbe oder Locken haben. Aber auch hier gilt: erst der Kontext würde erklären, was genau gemeint ist.

Er ist ähnlich wie sein Vater.

Das ist ein grammatikalischer Fehler, allerdings einer, der oft gemacht wird. Ähnlich zu sein ist eine Eigenschaft und ähnlich ist man "zu" etwas. "wie" füllt diesen Platz nicht, weil "wie" eine Gleichheit behauptet:

Diese Straße ist wie die andere.

Das bedeutet, daß diese Straße und die andere Straße irgendeine Eigenschaft (welche, das kommt wieder auf den Kontext an) haben, in der sie gleich sind. Wenn aber die beiden Straßen einander gleich sind, dann  können sie sich nur in der Ähnlichkeit gleich sein und dann stellt sich die Frage, zu was diese Ähnlichkeit besteht, die mit einem Adverbiale im Dativ ausgedrückt wird zB:

Er ist dem Bild an der Wand ähnlich wie sein Vater.

"Er" hat eine Eigenschaft (nämlich die Ähnlichkeit mit dem Bild), die er mit "sein Vater" teilt. Aber in Beziehung auf diese Eigenschaft sind die beiden gleich, nicht ähnlich.
"Wie" bedeutet: man hat zwei Dinge verglichen und festgestellt, daß sie (in der Hinsicht, in der der Vergleich stattgefunden hat) gleich sind. Ergibt dieser Vergleich, daß sie nicht gleich sind, dann verwendet man "als":

Ich bin so groß wie du.
Ich bin größer als du.

Aus genau dem Grund geht "ähnlich wie" nicht: das "wie" behauptet eine Gleichheit, das "ähnlich" das genaue Gegenteil, nämlich eine partielle Übereinstimmung, aber eben keine vollständige.
Nachbemerkung, nur für den Fall, daß der Einwand "fast so groß wie du" kommt:

Ich bin fast so groß wie du.

Hier wird die Größe des "du" als Maßstab genommen, der Vergleich durchgeführt und erst im Nachhinein die zunächst festgestellte Gleichheit durch "fast" modifiziert - ich bin so groß wie du, aber eben nur "fast" und nicht modifikationslos. Das selbe geht auch mit "als":

Ich bin beinahe schon größer als Du.

Auch hier wird zunächst eine Ungleichheit festgestellt, die dann aber relativiert wird.
Nachbemerkung 2: "ähnlich wie"
Es gibt tatsächlich eine Möglichkeit "ähnlich wie" zu verwenden, allerdings nur mit "ähnlich" als solchem Modifikator:

Er kann viele alte Sprachen, ähnlich wie sein Vater.

Hier wird der Vergleich "er<->sein Vater" angestellt, die Gleichheit (durch "wie" ausgedrückt) festgestellt und dann aber durch "ähnlich" abgeschwächt. Sein Vater konnte vielleicht mehr oder weniger alte Sprachen, vielleicht auch andere. Aber zunächst ist da eine Eigenschaft, in der sie sich gleichen, die sich aber unterschiedlich ausprägt, sodaß am Ende eine Ähnlichkeit herauskommt.
